# How to filter lists in Excel based on cell contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to learn how to filter two lists into a third, but only if they exist in both lists and have a checkmark in the corresponding column.

In my example below, AC and BB would be moved over to the "check list".  I can't figure out how to do this, because they never end up in the same order/cell.
Even just linking me to a tutorial would be excellent as I am completely lost.

[image: Example sheet]

Comment: This can be done using VBA Macro,, please confirm through comments that you could cope up with it, also [Edit] your post and add a new TAG `VBA` !!

Comment: This is doable using Power Query to join the two queries, with matching columns being the first and last.  But you have two columns in the results query that don't appear in your source tables.  You'll need to work that in.

Comment: May I know what character are used for the checkmark ? I cannot reproduce the character...